# Catching telegram system message about user enter/leave chat

Tags: python-3.x, telethon

I have a small telegram group, where my bot has admin rights. I want to send greetings to new users (and post some goodbye, when user leaves chat). In pytgbotAPI you can catch system messages by this handler, so bot can send its reply:

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['left_chat_member', 'new_chat_members'])
```

In telethon handler that catches all users messages don't get telegram system messages about user entering and leaving chat:

```
@bot.on(events.NewMessage(incoming=True))
```

Is there any chance to handle this messages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution:

```
from telethon import events

@client.on(events.ChatAction)
async def handler(event):
    # Welcome every new user
    if event.user_joined:
        await event.reply('Welcome!')
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).